# Link graphic library in Borland C++ 3.1

Tags: c, dos, borland-c++

I want to use graphic library in the DOS application.
I add `#include <graphics.h>` to my source file and build the application with the bcc:

```
bcc -3 -ms  -P -IC:\BC3\INCLUDE -LC:\BC3\LIB AMtest.c ExtMem.ASM
```

However, I get the link errors:

```
Turbo Link  Version 5.1 Copyright (c) 1992 Borland International

Error: Undefined symbol _closegraph in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _outtext in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _moveto in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _settextstyle in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _setcolor in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _settextjustify in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _graphresult in module amtest.c
Error: Undefined symbol _initgraph in module amtest.c
```

The `graphics.lib` is in the `c:\bc3\lib` folder. How do I link the graphic library?

Comment: Did you try: `bcc -3 -ms  -P -IC:\BC3\INCLUDE -LC:\BC3\LIB -lgraphics AMtest.c ExtMem.ASM ` ?

Comment: I get the error:
`Fatal: Unknown option`

Comment: It's `-lgraphic` (with `l` = 'ell').

Comment: I still get the error: `Fatal: Unknown option`

Comment: `-lgraphics` (with s at the end) ...

Comment: The problem is solved. The correct command is:
`bcc -3 -ms -P -IC:\BC3\INCLUDE -LC:\BC3\LIB graphics.lib AMtest.c ExtMem.ASM `

Comment: You should add that as answer. Otherwise this question ends up in searches for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong command. The correct command is:

```
bcc -3 -ms -P -IC:\BC3\INCLUDE -LC:\BC3\LIB graphics.lib AMtest.c ExtMem.ASM
```